# Jquery scrolltop function not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im creating a navbar that will fade in when I scroll a little bit down the page. 
My code works fine on desktop, but it does not work when I switch to mobile.

Here is the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var distance = 100;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('nav').css("background-color","rgba(6, 14, 49, 0.94)");
        }
        else {
          $('nav').css("background-color","rgba(6, 14, 49, 0.50)");
        }
   });
});
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions. I already tried switching $(window) to $('body') or $('html') and they didnt work

Comment: Do you get any errors in console? Have you tried to console some text to check if the values are correct

Comment: Post your html please. Your code works https://jsfiddle.net/xhoj3bzx/ my guess is your `nav` might be an ID or class and you forget to prefix it with the proper character. In the fiddle it is using jquery 3.2.1

Answer (score -1):

You can use $().scroll method to implement the desired result.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
      var distance = 50;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('nav').css("background-color","rgba(6, 14, 49, 0.94)");
        }
        else {
          $('nav').css("background-color","rgba(6, 14, 49, 0.50)");
        }
   });      
});
```

Comment: Makes no difference

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZYJKL check this codepen. It might help you.

Answer (score -2):

On mobile, the "scroll" event will be fired only when the scroll stops. for example, if you have a big slide on your mobile phone, and the window keep scrolling for 5 seconds, then the scroll event will be fired after 5 seconds.

Therefore, unfortunately, you cannot monitor the offset while the window is scrolling.

as an alternative, try to check some plugin that fake the scrolling which allow you to "monitor" the offset while "scrolling" . eg :https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

Comment: Im trying to have my menu bar change transparency as I scroll down the page. Perhaps the code above is wrong, maybe I dont need to use the function Scrolltop() at all. Do you have any ideas as to how I can rewrite my function to be both mobile and desktop friendly?

Comment: Your functions are fine, and as far as I know there is no delay in mobile scrolling

Comment: @KevinPrice if you don't want to use any plugin, maybe try to add "touchmove" to the event handler, so it will be "$(window).on('scroll touchmove', ....)" . for "50px" it should work.